# matplotlib.pyplot show() without clearing the figure

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` in interactive mode. I want to check that I've formatted the figure correctly using `plt.show()`, but every time I do the figure is cleared and I have to plot it again. I'd like to be able to view the plot in interactive mode without the figure clearing.

What happens:

```
>>> plt.plot(np.arange(5))
>>> plt.show()
<figure-displays>

>>> plt.show()
<nothing-happens>

>>> plt.savefig('my_figure.png')
<empty-file-is-saved>
```

What I want:

```
>>> plt.plot(np.arange(5))
>>> plt.show()
<figure-displays>

>>> plt.show()
<figure-displays>

>>> plt.savefig('my_figure.png')
<figure-is-saved>
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to be able to see the changes every time, you can save multiple files, and as long as you don't call plt.close(), the plots will just keep adding.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([5,1,4],[3,2,1])

plt.savefig('1.png')

plt.plot([3,2,1],[1,2,3])

plt.savefig('2.png')
```

[image: Images]

There might be many files, so it is best to do this in a New folder. If you are programming with the python shell only, this is what you can do to change directories:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = 'C:\\Users\\Caitlin\\Desktop\\New folder'
>>> os.chdir(path)
>>>
```

If you are using a python file, simply place the file into the New folder.

Or, you can simply add the path into `savefig()`:

```
plt.savefig('C:\\Users\\Caitlin\\Desktop\\New folder\\1.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you mean to then view the files in a GUI or something? Won't there be lots of files to cleanup afterwards?

Comment: Are you going to use python shell or python file?

Comment: I'm using the python shell

Comment: I added how into my post.